# it only display a number "2" when using while read line to redirect the content of one file to another

Tags: bash, shell

The content of the script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

tempconf="/tmp/test.file"
while read line
do
        echo $line
done < test.conf > $tempconf
```

The content of the test.conf is:

```
[PORT]
  tcp_ports=7000-7200
  udp_ports=7000-8000, 40000-49999

[H323H]
  maxSendThreads=10
  maxRecvThreads=10

[SDK]
  appPwd=1111111
  amsAddress=192.168.222.208:8888
```

The content of the output file "/tmp/test.file" is:

```
[PORT]
tcp_ports=7000-7200
udp_ports=7000-8000, 40000-49999

2
maxSendThreads=10
maxRecvThreads=10

[SDK]
appPwd=1111111
amsAddress=192.168.222.208:8888
```

The question is,why `[H323H]` turns out to be `2`. I'll be appreciated if anyone can explain it to me.

Comment: Do you have a file named `2` in the directory you're running that script from?

Comment: Run your script through shellcheck

Comment: @Shawn yes,there is a file named '2'.I'll delete id and try again.

Comment: This is a classic example of `Why-You-Need-To-Quote-` the variables in shell scripts...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[]` has a special meaning for the shell, it just means "a single character taken from any of the characters between the brackets". So when you run

```
echo [H323H]
```

the shell looks for a file named or H, or 2, or 3... If at least one file matches, `[H323H]` is replaced with all the matching file names in the output; otherwise it's reproduced as is.

source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/259385

Using quotes around `$line` would solve your problem without the need to check for files matching those characters (which would make the script not very robust)

```
#!/bin/bash

tempconf="/tmp/test.file"
while read -r line
do
    echo "$line"
done < test.conf > "$tempconf"
```